# How to show the equality of two descriptions for the cohomology of a non-finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, cohomology, group-cohomology

I am learning about group cohomology.

For a group $G$ and a $G$-mod $A$, we can define $X^n(G,A)=Map(G^{n+1},A)$, and get a resolution $0\to A\to X^\cdot$ and then define cohomology groups $H^n(G,A)$ for $n\geq 0$.

On the other hand, for the functor $F:A\to A^G$, we have the right derived functors $R^nF(-)$. I want to show that $H^n(G,A)=R^nF(A)$ without using theory about universal $\delta$-functor.

All the $X^n(G,*)$ are of the form $M=Map(G,A)$, so to show the equality, I want to show that such $M$ are acyclic ( for $R^nF(-)$ ), but I don't know how to do it.

Then I take $Map$ as the class of all such $G$-mod of the form $M=Map(G,A)$, and try to show that $Map$ is a class adapt to the functor $F$ (c,f, Gelfand, Sergei I.; Yuri Manin, Methods of homological algebra, ChapterIII.6.3,page 187), and then I have to show that given two sequences of $G$-module
 $ A\to B\to C$ and $ Map(G,A)\to Map(G,B)\to Map(G,C)$, if the second is exact, then so does the first. But I am not able to.

**Question:** How could I show that $H^n(G,A)=R^nF(A)$, maybe based on my idea or something unknown to me?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the universal $\delta$-functor? That makes life easier for this type of question. In any case, the explicit complex you write down is given by mapping a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ into a $G$-module. You can show acyclicity directly by using the lifting property for projective (in particular free) modules.

Comment: There's a well-established word for "non-finite", namely "infinite".